# argument of type 'int' is not iterable assistance needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to figure out this error `argument of type 'int' is not iterable` I'm basically making a numbered list containing 10 results. for the first result in the list I want to add a crown just after the number `1.`

Here is what I'm working with:

```
async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
    """Displays the top 10 members in the server"""

        async with self.bot.pool.acquire() as conn:
            res = await conn.fetch("SELECT user_id,lvl,xp,total_xp FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1 ORDER BY GREATEST(total_xp) DESC LIMIT 10", ctx.guild.id)
            #0: user_id, 1: lvl
            mess = "Here is a list of the current top ten active members."
            x = 1
            crown = f":crown: {x}" if 1 in x else f"{x}" #type int error happens here
            for ele in res:
                user = self.bot.get_user(int(ele[0]))
                mess +="**{}.** {} on **Level {: <3}** with **{: <4} XP**\n\n".format(crown,user.name,ele[1], ele[2])
                x+=1
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard", description=f"{mess}")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error seems to be happening on the line  `crown = f":crown: {x}" if 1 in x else f"{x}"`

Help appreciated.

Comment: `x` is a number, what are you expecting from `1 in x`?

Comment: IF the number is 1 in the list then place `:crown:` in front of that number is what  I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: _What_ list? x is a single number, `1`, which you assigned on the line immediately before the one that's erroring.

Comment: Above code creates a list of results numbered from 1 to 10  I'm wanting to identify  number 1 in the list and add a crown in front of that number.

Comment: Perhaps it does, but x is very definitely not that list. Have you tried some debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if 1 in x` is equivalent to `if 1 in 1` - `x` is an `int`, **not a list**, but in the comments you somehow keep insisting that it is a list (?).

I *think* what you're trying to accomplish is add a crown to the first entry in the list (the "number one" on the leaderboard) in which case you *don't* want to check if "1" is in a list, but you want to check if the current entry in the `for-loop` is the *first*. There will never be a `1` in `res` because `res` is a list of `tuple`s, not `int`s, and they don't contain an index either.

You can get the current `index` of an element in the list by iterating over both the index and the element at the same time with `enumerate()`, and then use that index to see what rank in the leaderboard they are. To print it nicely, their position is `index + 1` as indexing is 0-based. This way you can completely remove the `x` variable as well, as it doesn't do anything anyways.

```py
res = await conn.fetch("SELECT user_id,lvl,xp,total_xp FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1 ORDER BY GREATEST(total_xp) DESC LIMIT 10", ctx.guild.id)
#0: user_id, 1: lvl
mess = "Here is a list of the current top ten active members."

# Iterate over the list of results along with the index in the list (i)
for i, ele in enumerate(res):
    user = self.bot.get_user(int(ele[0]))
    # Res is ordered descending by your query, so the first element is the #1
    if i == 0:
        # Add a crown in front of the string if this is #1 (= element 0)
        mess += ":crown: "
    # Add the rest of the string, if a crown is necessary then it was prepended above ^
    mess +="**{}.** {} on **Level {: <3}** with **{: <4} XP**\n\n".format(i + 1,user.name,ele[1], ele[2])
```

Your question was *very* confusing though, and the comments didn't really help at first glance. `x` is not a list, it's an `int`, and `1` is **not** in your `res` list.

Comment: This would only return the 1st entry in the list with the crown? The other 9 entries in the list are missing.

Comment: No, it returns all of them, the last line is executed for every entry in the list so every entry is added to the `mess` string. It's **not** inside of that if-statement, which is probably where you messed up when trying to work this out? If you put the last line *inside* of the ``if`` then it will only add the first.

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answer my question. Your answer does work in theory but is not exactly what I was looking for. Your code seems to return entries from the database separately opposed to just appending the results to one full list. Here is a screenshot of the result https://ibb.co/YpJ1bBx

Comment: I don't have `ctx.send` anywhere in my answer so this is **not** because of me. If it sends multiple embeds then it looks like you added the `ctx.send` *inside* of the for-loop? You're supposed to put that *below* the loop, so it only sends **one** embed with **every name**. So my code *is* correct and *does* do what you were looking for. It appends everything to one full list in the `for-loop`, and *after* the for-loop you have the entire thing in one single embed that you're supposed to send **once**. The fact that the list grows one per one confirms that you put `send` inside of the loop.